# How to call jquery file at button click?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, button

Below is Jquery code from `form.js`...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var requiredFlag = ' * ';
    var requiredKey = $('input.required:first').next('span').text();
    requiredKey = requiredFlag + requiredKey.replace(/^\((.+)\)$/,"$1");
    var conditionalFlag = ' ** ';
    var conditionalKey = $('input.conditional:first').next('span').text();
    conditionalKey = conditionalFlag + conditionalKey.replace(/\((.+)\)/,"$1");

    $('form :input').filter('.required')
                    .next('span').text(requiredFlag).end()
                    .prev('label').addClass('req-label');

    $('form :input').filter('.conditional')
                    .next('span').text(conditionalFlag);

    $('<p></p>').addClass('field-keys')
                .append(requiredKey + '<br />')
                .append(conditionalKey)
                .insertBefore('#contact');
});
```

I want to call this file at button click which is placed in another file.
How can i achieve this?

**Note:Button is made using asp.net button control.**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you using asp `Button` then you need to make 1 of 2 posibilities

First is hardcode your function in `Button` `onClientClick` property like this:
`<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnExample" onClientClick=" function() {
    var requiredFlag = ' * ';var requiredKey = 'input.required:first').next('span').text();
    requiredKey = requiredFlag + requiredKey.replace(/^\((.+)\)$/,"$1"); var conditionalFlag = ' ** '; var conditionalKey = $('input.conditional:first').next('span').text(); conditionalKey = conditionalFlag + conditionalKey.replace(/\((.+)\)/,"$1"); $('form :input').filter('.required')
                    .next('span').text(requiredFlag).end()                   .prev('label').addClass('req-label');
    $('form :input').filter('.conditional')                    .next('span').text(conditionalFlag);
    $('<p></p>').addClass('field-keys').append(requiredKey + '<br />')                .append(conditionalKey)
                .insertBefore('#contact');
}"/>`

or Second is to write in your js file or inside `script` tags:

```
var myFunctionClientClick = function() {
var requiredFlag = ' * ';
var requiredKey = $('input.required:first').next('span').text();
requiredKey = requiredFlag + requiredKey.replace(/^\((.+)\)$/,"$1");
var conditionalFlag = ' ** ';
var conditionalKey = $('input.conditional:first').next('span').text();
conditionalKey = conditionalFlag + conditionalKey.replace(/\((.+)\)/,"$1");

$('form :input').filter('.required')
                .next('span').text(requiredFlag).end()
                .prev('label').addClass('req-label');

$('form :input').filter('.conditional')
                .next('span').text(conditionalFlag);

$('<p></p>').addClass('field-keys')
            .append(requiredKey + '<br />')
            .append(conditionalKey)
            .insertBefore('#contact');}
```

then write simply `<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnExample" onClientClick="myFunctionClientClick"/>`

hope it helps:)

Answer (score 0):

You can use ***[`.getScript()`](http://docs.jquery.com/action/edit/Getscript)*** method.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // within dom ready function
    $('#bton').on('click', function() {
       $.getScript('form.js?' + (new Date()).getTime(), function() {
          // do something after file load
       });
    });
});
```

Here, `(new Date().getTime())` is for prevent cache issue and `#your_button` should be replaced with appropriate button's `id` or `class` or other selector.

Comment: I added following in head section of aspx code but it didn't work.

<script type="text/javascript">
$('#bton').on('click', function() {
   $.getScript('form.js');
})
</script>